In a network with two DHCP servers, how does one server know about leases that a client obtained from the other
A client broadcasts a DHCP discover message. Two servers received and  reply with offers message, but client accepts the 1st reached msg from 1st server.
What happens to the 2nd server offer message?
How does the second server know the client is occupied?
Could anyone please explain?
If possible advise me with any website?

this question lacks information. It does not provide details about the network configuration, server, and IPs used, nor does it specify the desired end state imho.

A DHCP transaction looks something like this:

Client sends a DISCOVER message
Server sends an OFFER message with a specific address
Client broadcasts a REQUEST for that specific address
Server sends an ACK message to confirm

In the situation where there are two DHCP servers, the address in the REQUEST broadcast will only match the address OFFERED by the first server. The second server will see that the REQUEST doesn't match, so it knows that the address it offered has not been consumed by the client.
Wikipedia has a more detailed overview if you would like additional information.

The REQUEST is broadcast, notifying the 2nd server of its offer not being taken.

I've corrected the answer.

do we speak about a rouge dhcp or a failover? how has it been configured?
